# Vuforia IOS cylinder example - Add button

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have successfully built the sample application from Vuforia. I am interested in taking the Cylinder Tracking and replacing the soccer ball that rotates around the soda can with a button that does not rotate but sits at a certain position in relation to the can (the center of the tracking image).

I am new to iOS development and am not sure quite how to do this. Ideally this would be done programmatically.

I was able to add a button to the `CylinderTargetsViewController.mm` using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
 [button setTitle:@"Gossamer Rules" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button sizeToFit];
 button.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 60);
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    UIApplication *mySafari = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];
[mySafari openURL:myURL];
}
```

However this adds a button to the screen whether the target is found or not and it has no spatial relationship to the target.

I tried moving this code into `CylinderTargetsEAGLView.mm` but got an error on line `[self.view addSubview:button];` saying view was not a property of self.

I realize this is probably not the right approach. I'm thinking the button needs to be rendered as an openGl object or something so that it is 3 dimensional and can be seen from an angle when moving the target.

Has anyone done this or have any clue how it may be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use the Vuforia Unity Package as there is a much steeper learning curve trying to learn pure OpenGL programming. The Unity route has much larger community support, and more tutorials / information are available.